# Keep on doing an action while button is pressed after long click

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, onlongclicklistener

Sorry if the title makes no sense. What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to long click a button, and once the long click is detected, to keep on doing a certain task.

To put it into context, I have a view with a background that changes to a random color on click. I would like to have the background keep on changing color as long as I long click the button. So, basically, upon long click and keeping the button pressed, the background will keep on changing.

Thank you very much folks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with `view.setOnLongClickListener()` because an OnLongClickListener has a very specific way of functioning. As soon as enough time has passed, the listener will activate and the code is run.

What you want is to use `view.setOnTouchListener()`. This way you can set a Timer when it detects a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. Once the timer is long enough to equal a long click, you can have it trigger your color changing code repeatedly until the OnTouchListener detects a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. That's when you can stop the color changing code.

Comment: Oh I see...Thank you so much... :)

Comment: Hi there. How can I repeatedly trigger the code? Is there a special method? I seem to be lost...  Thank you :)

Comment: @EdwinYoubirdmurali Normally, a while loop with a condition to stop when `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is detected is enough to repeatedly trigger code. But keep in mind that since you're changing the background color, you should also add in a delay before repeating your code, otherwise, the colors will be changing so many times a second that our eyes won't be able to view the proper change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I really appreciate it :)